# Custom button view (control) with bindable properties set in a custom renderer not being shown in-app or designer

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've recently been working through many Xamarin.Forms courses. I decided that I wanted to create my own control that exposes my own bindable properties. I created a BindableProperty titled 'isCaps' in a customised button:

```
 public class CustomButton : Button
    {
        public static BindableProperty IsUpperCaseProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsUpperCase), typeof(bool), typeof(CustomButton), false);

        public bool IsUpperCase
        {
            get => (bool)GetValue(IsUpperCaseProperty);
            set => SetValue(IsUpperCaseProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

Seems good, right?

So I created a custom renderer that will add the functionality like so:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomButton), typeof(CustomButtonRenderer))]
namespace ButtonLowerUpper.Droid.CustomRenderers
{
    public class CustomButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        public CustomButtonRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Element is CustomButton button)
            {
                Control.SetAllCaps(button.IsUpperCase);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Okay, so I now I created a page like so:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ButtonLowerUpper.CustomControls"
             x:Class="button.MainPage">
    <controls:CustomButton Text="hi" IsUpperCase=false/>
</ContentPage>
```

Now - the strange thing is - nothing is being updated in my app NOR my designer:

[image]

My button is still in uppercase even when set to false. I have followed every instruction required - and I have no idea why this is not working.

I am looking for help regarding this - I want to create my own custom control library but that will not be possible until step 1 is resolved.

Thanks,

Right now I will continue finishing the Pluralsight course on Xamarin.Forms but when someone provides an answer I will check it and see if it works and if it does I will set this as a correct answer.

tommy99

Comment: If I have not explained something well please reply to this comment - thank you.

Comment: I tested your code and it's working fine. I'm assuming `IsUpperCase=false` instead of `IsUpperCase="False"` this is a typo, Anyways, I don't know what the issue is.

Comment: Delete the bin/obj files and try again , or maybe try in device instead of simulator.

Comment: Hello Shubhan Tyagi - that was a typo (my real solution says "False"). First of all tell me what Xamarin.Forms version you're on. Maybe you could let me access your solution via GitHub if that's OK? (I don't know if it's allowed.)

Comment: It'd be great if you could make a repos via GitHub so I could assess if the problem is not related to code. Thanks,

Comment: Like @ShubhamTyagi said, change the xaml. `<controls:CustomButton IsUpperCase="False" Text="hi" />` The other code you provided works on my side. Please check my screenshot. https://imgur.com/uaxbxiK The first button is the normal button control. The second one is the custombutton.